# How to fix Window Height using JQuery to adjust Panels with overflow-y scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Window scroll is disabled using overflow hidden property in html block. I have `<div>` elements which `display` property is set to `inline-block`.   Those elements have a fixed height say 100px  and `overflow-y: scroll`. On *Mac OS X*, the content inside those `<div>` elements is scrollable and visible, the panels cover bottom of the window, but on *Windows* due to window height the content at the end of the panel is not fully scrollable. How to fix this issue?[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0mrxLLe/)

Comment: Kindly request you to post your HTML/CSS code to get the solution.

Comment: Share the code you have tried yet.

Comment: Though judging form your question could say is give padding-bottom:50px; to your the most bottom div among both. 50px is just random, try whatever suits you better.

Comment: Create similar issue in Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

To left panel and right panel divs, We have to add a parent div with css height 100% property.  Set left & right panel height using jquery by subtracting header height from window height and give left & panel overflow-y scroll property.  Such that it covers the window height and panel also scrolls till end of theirs content.